How to get all transaction and user information from bigquery Near and indexer-lake-framework?
I realised that the transactions and user account information from bigquery-public-data.crypto_near_mainnet_us and near-lake-framework is not block height 0, and it is starting record from 2020-07-21 or later.
is there anyway to get all transaction and user information from the begining? only index-lake-explorer able to do it?

The very first block height for mainnet (also called Genesis block) is 9820210.
NEAR Protocol blockchain has indeed started from block #0 along with the it's development start, but went through a few "hard forks" (actually re-genesis) processes and official mainnet launch happened around the date you've mentioned in the question.
Note around re-genesis
What actually happens when blockchain does re-genesis. Somebody creates a snapshot of current blockchain state (all accounts, contract, its state) to a genesis.json file, to avoid confusions with the same block heights in the future it was decided to start a new blockchain history from that initial state, but mark a starting block height with the "next" block height from the "old" blockchain.
Then validators agree to start a new network from that snapshot and that's what happened around August 2020.
So you won't find the block height #0 just because it never existed from the point of view of the current blockchain, since it has started from block #9820210

cool ! thanks for explaining, ya i get from near-lake-framework is starting from 9820210
